# Using BoolToObjectConverter with TranslateExtension True/FalseObject does not return translated string

Tags: xamarin.forms, translation, ivalueconverter, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am using the `BoolToObjectConverter` from Xamarin Community Toolkit (XCT) in my XAML file. The `TrueObject` and `FalseObject` properties are set to translatable strings where I use the `TranslateExtension` from XCT:

```
xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
...
<xct:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="Converter" TrueObject="{xct:Translate YesAnswer}" FalseObject="{xct:Translate NoAnswer}" />
...
<Label Text="{Binding Foo, Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" />
```

I would have expected that the `Label` text would have been the translated yes or no answer.

Unfortunately the actual `Label` output is

> Xamarin.Forms.Binding

The issue could be solved by not using a converter but instead using a `DataTrigger` to set the `Label.Text` depending on the value of `Foo`. However, this clutters the XAML code; I would like to stick to using the `BoolToObjectConverter`. What can I do to obtain the translated string output instead of just the `Binding` type?

**EDIT**
Alternatively, I could add `x:TypeArguments="BindingBase"` in the converter definition, since this is the return type of the `TranslateExtension.ProvideValue` method, but this does not make any difference to the output result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with was to subclass XCT `TranslateExtension` and implement `IMarkupExtension` for a `string` return value. This way I could use the subclass to obtain translated strings in the converter.

**Implementation**

```
public class TranslateToStringExtension : Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Extensions.TranslateExtension, IMarkupExtension<string>
{
    public new string ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider) as Binding;
        string path;
        var value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(path = binding?.Path?.Trim('[', ']'))
            ? null
            : LocalizationResourceManager.Current.GetValue(path);
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<xct:BoolToObjectConverter 
  x:Key="Converter" 
  TrueObject="{local:TranslateToString YesAnswer}" 
  FalseObject="{local:TranslateToString NoAnswer}" />
```